# NAD27 to NAD83, saving AFTER transformation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, table, latitude-longitude, nad83

I need to measure the distance (with the ruler) of points from two different layers. One layer is NAD83 and the other is NAD27. When importing the NAD27 csv file, I specified it was NAD27. Then I used: Toolbox-> Data Management -> Projections and Transformations -> Project and I projected from the input coordinate system of NAD27 to the output coordinate system of NAD83.

The issue is that I have a ton of CSV files, each with data from different projections (there is a column that specifies projection). I use Microsoft Access to connect a lot of tables and then extract the data I need, save in a table, and import to ArcGIS. The problem is that after I just transformed my NAD27 to NAD83, the lat/long in the actual table is still the same, so if I join the tables and extract data later on, I will have to do the transformations all over again.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Field Calculator to recalculate the Lat/Long once you've done the data transformation.

If you need to preserve the original values (for some reason), then add two new columns and calc those with the NAD83 values.

Comment: There also a tool, [Add XY Coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Add_XY_Coordinates/001700000032000000/).

Comment: You both gave great advice. I found the tool for "Add XY Coordinates (Data Management)." I ended up using that but also did a quick practice with the Field Calculator, in case I go that route in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @WolverineTime - YW. mkennedy's suggestion is faster/better for most applications. I should've mentioned it for a more complete answer. NOTE: Using the Field Calculator allows one to customize the field "values" and the Add XY Coords tool does not. Also using the tool *may* overwrite existing values - which can be good if you want it and quite bad if you don't.

Comment: Hi  user23715, I appreciate your suggestion of using the Field Calculator. Alas, I am still at a level in which I do not know what to actually input in the field calculator, so that it outputs the newly transformed lat/long.

Comment: @WolverineTime The answer is a bit confusing in that you don't access the Field Calculator per se. To add XY coordinates you actually *Calculate Geometry* (another choice when you right-click a column heading in an attribute table).

Comment: @ChrisW - Yeah, that *could* be confusing. I always recommend preserving old (but good) data. By adding the new columns and using Calculate Geometry instead of the Field Calc the user only needs to make sure that the Data Frame is in the proper coordinate system - in this case NAD83.